# How to combine 4 font styles into one file?

Tags: fonts, font-face

I want to use a custom font as a @font-face but i got 4 different files for each style: regular, bold, italic, bold italic.

Is there a tool to combine them into one file so we don't get 4 HTTP requests?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same problem now :)